# ¿Como separar mi factory en otro archivo .js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas, angularjs-scope, angularjs-injector

mi duda es la siguiente, estoy aprendiendo AngularJS, y estoy realizando el código para un login, donde he realizado factory's, pero todo esta en un mismo archivo (app.js) como se muestra a continuación:

`(function(){
    var app = angular.module('login', ['ngStorage']);

```
//factoria para guardar y eliminar sesiones con sessionStorage
app.factory('sesionesControl', function($sessionStorage){
    return {
        //obtenemos una sesión //getter
        get : function() {
            return $sessionStorage.LoginAIRSoftware;
        },
        //creamos una sesión //setter
        set : function(val) {
            return $sessionStorage.LoginAIRSoftware = val;
        },
        //limpiamos una sesión
        unset : function() {
            return $sessionStorage.LoginAIRSoftware = undefined;
        }
    };
});



//Controlador para loginForm
app.controller('loginForm', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', 'authUsers', 'sesionesControl', 
    function($scope, $window, $location, authUsers, sesionesControl){

    $scope.inicio = function(){
        if($scope.usuario === null || $scope.password === null){
            $scope.mensajeError = "Uno o más campos se encuentran vacios";
            $scope.mensajeShow = true;
        }else{
            authUsers.login($scope.usuario, $scope.password)
            .success(function(res) {
                if(res.data === 'Correcto'){
                    sesionesControl.set($scope.usuario);
                    $window.location.href = 'home.html';
                }else {
                    $scope.mensajeError = "USUARIO y/o CONTRASEÑA invalidos. Intente nuevamente.";
                    $scope.mensajeShow = true;
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                $scope.mensajeError = "Error al conectar con Servidor";
                $scope.mensajeShow = true;
            });
        }
    };

}]);
})();`
```

Quisiera saber como separar el factory "sesionesControl" en otro archivo llamado factorySesionesControl.js y que mi archivo app.js lo pueda utilizar. Pondría lo que eh intentado, pero es inútil ya que no funciona, y por eso agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, tan solo tienes que poner el código de la factory en ese fichero aparte e incluirlo después del app en el index.html

Es decir, index.html:

```
<head>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="factorySesionesControl.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podria ser asi,creas tu archivo por separado factory.js y dentro

```
angular.module('login').factory('sesionesControl', function($sessionStorage){
    return {
        //obtenemos una sesión //getter
        get : function() {
            return $sessionStorage.LoginAIRSoftware;
        },
        //creamos una sesión //setter
        set : function(val) {
            return $sessionStorage.LoginAIRSoftware = val;
        },
        //limpiamos una sesión
        unset : function() {
            return $sessionStorage.LoginAIRSoftware = undefined;
        }
    };
});
```

Podrias hacer lo mismo con los controladores,directivas,etc
Simplemente en ves de utilizar una variable en un archivo "app" lo remplazas por "angular.module('login').controller"  por ejemplo,etc,suerte!